# Cannot get COUNT() to work when using a Haversine calculation in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have got the Haversine to work retrieving rows meeting a distance criteria but cannot get the Mysql COUNT() function to work. Here is part of my code:

```
$query1 = "
SELECT COUNT(\"$table.*\") AS numrows1, outcodepostcodes.lat, outcodepostcodes.lng
,111.045* DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS($latpoint))
             * COS(RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lat))
             * COS(RADIANS($longpoint) - RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lng))
            + SIN(RADIANS($latpoint))
             * SIN(RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lat)))) AS distance
FROM $table
LEFT JOIN outcodepostcodes
ON UPPER(\"$table.postcode\")=outcodepostcodes.outcode
HAVING ROUND(distance,2) <= $choosedistn
ORDER BY rent $reihenach LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage
";
```

The $queries are then processed as below:

```
$result1  = mysql_query($query1) or die('Error, query1 failed:' .mysql_error());
$result2  = mysql_query($query2) or die('Error, query2 failed:' .mysql_error());
$row1     = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$row2     = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$numrows1 = $row1['numrows1'];
$numrows2 = $row2['numrows2'];
```

I get NULL for $numrows. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes here are wrong `COUNT(\"$table.*\") AS numrows1`.

Make it like this

```
COUNT(`$table`.*) AS numrows1
```

Comment: @Alexander Mitsev, thanks for trying to help but that doesn't make any difference

Comment: In fact, what you are suggesting is wrong. It will throw up a mysql error